# Using Typescript’s type system to create strongly typed filter functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I’m trying to use the TypeScript type system to create a very strongly typed ‘filter’-like function that operates on a collection (not a simple array though).
Below is an example of what I’m trying to achieve:

```
type ClassNames = 'B' | 'C' | 'D'; // I know the COMPLETE list 

declare class A {
    protected constructor();
    className: ClassNames;
    attr1: string;
}

declare class B extends A {
    private constructor();
    className: 'B';
    attr2: string;
    attr4: number;
}

declare class C extends A {
    private constructor();
    className: 'C';
    attr3: number;
    attr4: string;
}

declare class D extends A {
    private constructor();
    className: 'D';
    attr4: string | number;
}

declare class Filter<T> {
    has<U extends keyof (A|B|C|D), V extends U[keyof U]>(propName: U, propVal: V): Filter<T & {U: V}>;
    //                                                                                         ^ This is obviously wrong
    all(): T[];
}

let g = new Filter<A>();
let x = g.has('className', 'B');
let y = g.has('attr4', 'whatever');
type Y = typeof y; // I want this to be Filter<C | D>
type X = typeof x; // I want this to be Filter<B>
```

A few notes:

- I know the entire class hierarchy and all classes are direct descendants of A.
- I will be generating the class declarations with a program, so verbosity or DRY violations are not an issues
- I’m perfectly fine with using the latest beta release of TypeScript
- At this point I only care about the declarations, the implementation seems trivial in comparison

I’ve tried using conditional types, but to no avail (my knowledge here is probably lacking). I also feel `infer` might be relevant to the solution, but I can’t see where to put it or how to use it.

Is this achievable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `console.log()`, could you remove that?  What is `ClassNames`? Can you remove that and replace it with `string` or something defined?  Anyway, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb0ndw) meet your needs?  I replaced references to `A` in `Filter` with references to a specific union of all known subclasses `B | C | D`; if you leave `A` it's likely to show up in places you don't want.  Anyway if that works I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, you’re very close to what I’m aiming for. The `console.log` is illustrative only, but a cosmetic `type` would have been better. `type ClassNames = B | C | D` was the first line of the snippet, I’ll edit the question shortly. The reason for the Filter class being templated is to allow for a Builder-like pattern with more tightly scoped types in each subsequent filter object. I feel like this is the right approach

Comment: Unfortunately I understand very little of that comment .  `console.log` is illustrative of what? What is a "cosmetic `type`"? If `ClassNames` were `B | C | D` as opposed to some subtype of `string` like `"B" | "C" | "D"` then things would just break; you don't want the name of the class to be an instance of the class, you want a string, right?  When you say it "was" the first line of the snippet, are you speaking counterfactually? Do you mean it "should have been" the first line?  

Comment: @jcalz it was the first line of the snippet, formatting was hiding it. I’ve edited the snippet, I hope it’s clear what I mean now. By cosmetic I mean a type declaration meant to show the result of an underlying type calculation, I’m not referring to a well-established terminology. Indeed, `ClassNames` is a union of string literal types, not classes, as you point out. I hope this clears the confusion

Comment: Okay, thanks.  So does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/m3yXyw) constitute a solution for you? I'm just trying to make sure that you don't have a problem with it before I spend time writing up an answer based on it.

Comment: @jcalz You should definitely write an answer - I’ll accept it gladly, as it answers the question completely. That being said, I have one more tidbit I’d love for you to address: if I add `let y = x.has('attr3', 12345)` the final type of this is (correctly) evaluated as `Filter<never>`, however `attr3` is still considered a valid argument, even though x already has a type that prevents `attr3` from being an option as an argument. Regardless of whether addressing this is viable, please post an answer, as you’ve already put significant effort into this question and you deserve the reputation gain

Comment: Oh, sure.  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wOPRdN) address that concern? If so I'll use it in my answer.

Comment: @jcalz yes, this version is great! Please post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to refactor to something like this.  First, it's helpful to have a type corresponding to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all acceptable subclasses of `A`; I've called this `Classes`.  From this you can *compute* `ClassNames` if it turns out you need that type:

```
type Classes = B | C | D;
type ClassNames = Classes["className"];
```

Then we need to define some utility types to help describe what we want `Filter<T>` to do.

---

Given a union type `T`, we'd like `AllKeys<T>` to give us the union of keys that appear in *any* member of the union `T`.  A straightforward `keyof T` doesn't work because a value of type `{a: string, c: string} | {b: number, c: string}` is only known to have a key named `c`; it may or may not have an `a` key, so `keyof` can only return `"c"` here.  We want `"a" | "b" | "c"` instead.  So `AllKeys<T>` has to *distribute* `keyof` over unions in `T`.  Here's how:

```
type AllKeys<T> =
  T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
```

That's a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

We also need a similar way to perform [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) on a union type `T` and a key `K` where not every member of `T` is known to have a key `K`.  Call it `SomeIdx<T, K>`.  Again, we can't do a straightforward `T[K]` because the compiler will not let you index into a type with a key it isn't known to have.  And again, we need to distribute indexed accesses across unions in `T`:

```
type SomeIdx<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends unknown ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] :
  never : never;
```

And finally, we need to write `Select<T, K, V>` which selects the member(s) of union type `T` which is known to have a key `K` and where type `V` is an acceptable value for the property at that key.  This is the filtering operation you're looking for.  Yet again we need to distribute the operation across unions in `T`; for each such member we check if `K` is a known key and if `V` is assignable to the value type at that key:

```
type Select<T, K extends PropertyKey, V> =
  T extends unknown ? K extends keyof T ? V extends T[K] ? T :
  never : never : never;
```

---

There's our utility types, and now we can define `Filter<T>`:

```
declare class Filter<T extends Classes = Classes> {
  has<K extends AllKeys<T>, V extends SomeIdx<T, K>>(
    propName: K, propVal: V): Filter<Select<T, K, V>>
  all(): T[];
}
```

Note that we are restricting `T` to be assignable to `Classes`, the union of known subclasses of `A`.  We don't want to allow `A` itself here, because we really don't want to see `A` appear in the type of the result of `has()`.  And `T` [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `Classes` so the type `Filter` by itself means `Filter<B | C | D>`.

For a given `T`, the current set of subclasses of `A` that a `Filter<T>` has been narrowed to, we want the `has()` method to accept a `propName` argument of a type `K` that is constrained to be assignable to `AllKeys<T>` (that is, `propName` should be one of the known keys of any of the types in `T`).  And we want it to accept a `propVal` argument of type `V` that is constrained to be assignable to `SomeIdx<T, K>` (that is, `propVal` should be of a type known to be appropriate for the `propName` key for at least one of the members of `T`).  Finally, we return `Filter<Select<T, K, V>>`, thus narrowing `T` to just those members with a known key `K` and a value type appropriate for `V`.

---

We've defined it, let's test it out:

```
let g = new Filter(); // Filter<Classes>

let x = g.has('className', 'B');
type X = typeof x; // type X = Filter<B>

let y = g.has('attr4', 'whatever');
type Y = typeof y; // type Y = Filter<C | D>

let z = x.has('attr3', 12345); // error!
// Argument of type '"attr3"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof B'.
```

Looks good.  Starting from a `Filter<Classes>`, we can narrow to `Filter<B>` by checking `has('className', 'B')`. Or we can narrow to `Filter<C | D>` by checking `has('attr4', 'whatever'`) since both `B` and `D` will accept a `string`-valued `attr4` property.  And once we have a `Filter<B>`, it will only accept a `propName` from `B`, so `"attr3"` is rejected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABNGBnViCCiDexGIAOcA9gC6QUjIkB2qZcArhGSXABQCUA3PsrHQA5GAFswALkQBhQahHjUfAjDKMAjFIZwAlrQDmfAL7BQkWAgFoMAIURgAHhVogM2PAWI6AbqqQQ6bRY2Tl5+FGExSUQAchsY5URVRgAmLUY9Q35kuAAWKVomUQAjMDhjU3AUSwiMaXsnMBc3XH4vXwoaekZg9m5E2oVomOkE7LU4AGYCotLy8cZ8xG1MirNq-zlEABEG51csVs9dDv9AntY+sIJBqKkY7bGVCaWVg0QAH0RCkrK1sgAnoQkLJrGAMABeRB2L71L7bPiA4EyORDSEosGoADaACJbuIcQBdPjAJFITBQKAAaTAANQAB4ACoAPkQEP4jL2TQOTFoAGtaCQAO60RAAfkQfNpJAAZohOQUwN4-qYyYgAMokcQASRADiZABpEFSuc1EAAFUjAuCAmkA1nsgicxz7DC8gXC0USk0u7kYKUA2Xy8XyrFUwmICT8WhKsqR76x+akoFIdVgKCUQ3G00HS0ka222lGgBqDo5Obd-MFIpDPsaZoDQc5EuLFdD4ZDCujifjMeVcF7iZJVQsm2siAAYjooBQ4Ey26D0OC2Ril6hWR5EAALND0uuurCUu0MlkltuanV6rNU5nMjj8Y75oZSKlG4j54swKBSYtcKRTmcynpNMM1Ya8S1vbJKW4KRGSxYlgBMYAMzIRB9BXGMhUnadZ36RAAHp8OwwC50XVBwWZUwUMQBwV30AA6HdUA4GJ8TAGIjTiGIwjVAANFcySDBweAIoi+JXADZ3pGxKOQsBUIBOjGLQFiclyDjYiFHcKH7bjERTRAAE0BJTIMAREwjEDVYyoUkoC4R2WTqIALxXBxlOYmIckmDT1BSSZcgAVl4UT7DgUg4AAQmASzMDgfQiiaVCgzVGIcW8nEYkQHQMEFVDrB0fRaBgYoMyskgiHgKJZ0QFKDJiRs5XieigA)